# Set Memory Limit and Time Limit in PHPExcel

Tags: php, arrays, phpexcel

I have many arrays and i print it into excel using PHPExcel. Some times it need many column to write. It is over 5000 column.

The problem is sometime even the column is over from 5000 column, it can be print succeesfully but sometime it show as corrupted file.

I have read this : [Why PHPExcel does not allow to write more than 5000 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895230/why-phpexcel-does-not-allow-to-write-more-than-5000-rows)

But still im confusing.

This is my code :

```
 <?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli')
    die('This example should only be run from a Web Browser');

/** Include PHPExcel */
require_once 'PHPExcel.php';

// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Set document properties
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Valerian Timothy")
                             ->setLastModifiedBy("Valerian Timothy")
                             ->setTitle("Excel Document")
                             ->setSubject("Data Mining")
                             ->setDescription("Count how many words exists.")
                             ->setKeywords("Data Mining")
                             ->setCategory("Data Mining");


// Add some data
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'Username')
            ->setCellValue('B1', 'Jumlah')
            ->setCellValue('C1', 'Hashtag')
            ->setCellValue('D1', 'Jumlah')
            ->setCellValue('E1', 'Etc')
            ->setCellValue('F1', 'Jumlah')
            ->setCellValue('G1', 'Date')
            ->setCellValue('H1', 'Jumlah');

// Miscellaneous glyphs, UTF-8
if($_SESSION['username'] != "")
{
    $w = 2;
    foreach($_SESSION['username'] as $user => $jumlah)
    {
        $cellUser = 'A' . $w;
        $cellJumlah = 'B' . $w;
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue($cellUser, $user)
        ->setCellValue($cellJumlah, $jumlah);
        $w++;
    }
}

if($_SESSION['hashtag'] != "")
{
    $x = 2;
    foreach($_SESSION['hashtag'] as $hashtag => $jumlah)
    {
        $cellUser = 'C' . $x;
        $cellJumlah = 'D' . $x;
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue($cellUser, $hashtag)
        ->setCellValue($cellJumlah, $jumlah);
        $x++;
    }
}

if($_SESSION['etc'] != "")
{
    $y = 2;
    foreach($_SESSION['etc'] as $etc => $jumlah)
    {
        $cellUser = 'E' . $y;
        $cellJumlah = 'F' . $y;
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue($cellUser, $etc)
        ->setCellValue($cellJumlah, $jumlah);
        $y++;
    }
}

if(!empty($_SESSION['tanggal']))
{
    $z = 2;
    foreach($_SESSION['tanggal'] as $date => $jumlah)
    {
        $cellUser = 'G' . $z;
        $cellJumlah = 'H' . $z;
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue($cellUser, $date)
        ->setCellValue($cellJumlah, $jumlah);
        $z++;
    }
}

foreach(range('A','H') as $columnID) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($columnID)
        ->setAutoSize(true);
}
// Rename worksheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');


// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$today = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Data-Mining'.$today.'.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
session_destroy();
?>
```

Could you help me to fix it ?

Comment: `ini_set('max_execution_time', 9999);` and `ini_set('memory_limit', '24');`  <--- is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: Do you really mean 5000 columns? or 5000 rows?

Comment: But what is confusing you? Check memory usage, check for timeouts; check your logs and look at the content of "corrupted" files in a text editor to see if there are any PHP error messages in those files that have corrupted them.

Comment: If memory is your issue, then use cell caching to reduce the memory footprint, and/or increase the amount of memory that you allow PHP to use

Comment: Sorry.. I mean rows. @MarkBaker.

Comment: I have trying yours but still got nothing @KraangPrime.

Comment: I still don't know which problem i have. The file just showing that is corrupted.

Comment: Open that file in a __text editor__.... look for anything like leading/trailing whitespace characters, plaintext error messages, etc